# Xamarin.Forms: Overriding back button and OnOptionsItemSelected

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to override software back button in the toolbar, but there obviously is no simple way. Currently, I am trying to do something on my own...somehow..

Looks like I will need the OnOptionsItemSelected method, but for some reason it is not called.

This is my OnOptionsItemSelected override, ignore the stuff in it..

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) {
        // check if the current item id is equals to the back button id
        if (item.ItemId == 16908332)
        {
            // retrieve the current xamarin forms page instance
            var selected = item;
            // Some random stuff will come here.
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // since its not the back button click, pass the event to the base
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

I have seen that you need to do some "initialization" in the OnCreate method in MainActivity to make it run:

```
if (FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) is AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar)
        {
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
```

But for some reason, I cant "find" this AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar. For some reason, AppCompat doesnt exists. I tried installing Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, but it is still not found. Any idea?

Comment: The top back button needs to have a different behavior of the native back button of Android?

Comment: I would like to implement that "Changes not saved, are you sure you wanna go back?" stuff, ye

Comment: Yes, but, if the user clicks on the BackButton of Android, the native (the one below), will do the same thing or you want to one do something and the other do another thing?

Comment: Oh, you mean the "hardware" button of the device? I handle that with overriding OnBackButtonPressed() method. (They should do the same thing, yes)

Comment: It's weird because normally the two Buttons do the same thing. I don't know if you tried to use only `OnBackButtonPressed()` or just override in the class that you need to use or create a condition in your `OnBackButtonPressed()` in MainActivity.cs for this case, e.g: `if(isToPrompt) { ShowPrompt(); }`. Or even you can handle it using `NavigationStack`. Just ideas.

Comment: overriding OnBackButtonPressed() in the class or OnBackPressed() in mainActicity works only for hardware button (android button in the bottom), but nothing works for "software" button in the toolbar... Do you know how to "call" OnOptionsItemSelected() in the mainActicity?

Comment: In Forms, the ToolbarItem support button behavior. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/toolbaritem#define-button-behavior

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT This only works for user defined ToolbarItems though, right? The behaviour of the back button included in the toolbar of a NavigationPage can't be overridden that way.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to override software back button in the toolbar, but there obviously is no simple way. Currently, I am trying to do something on my own...somehow..
>
> I would like to implement that "Changes not saved, are you sure you
> wanna go back?" stuff, ye

I've had the same issue and I also came to the conclusion that it was impossible to prevent a Page being closed when the NavigationPage's toolbar back button was pressed.

Now this was back in 2019, not sure if there is another way that I'm not aware of.

One way to handle this is asking the user a yes/no question like "Do you want to save the changes?" AFTER the page was closed. This way the user still has the choice to save or discard changes but it won't be possible to "cancel" the back navigation.

If you need full control over the when the page can be closed, consider navigating to the page modally, i.e. use

```
Application.NavigationProxy.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page));
```

instead of

```
NavigationPage.PushAsync(page);
```

There will be no automatically added back button in the toolbar of a modal page. It can only be closed explicitly by one of the actions you define.

If you use modal navigation, be aware that Android's hardware back button can still close the page, so `OnBackButtonPressed()` still needs to be handled.